# Do quarks have a non-zero electric dipole moment?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, dipole-moment

It is written here, [in this PSE link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/700922/183646) that an electron has a measured perfect spherical charge density therefore a zero electric dipole moment *(i.e. perfect monopole charge)*.

My question is, are quarks also theoretically predicted or experimentally verified to have a zero electric dipole moment by the standard model (SM)? Thus having a perfect spherical charge distribution? This would however contradict the fact that [neutrons have a non-zero electric dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_electric_dipole_moment).

Are there any other elementary charged particles in the SM table that we know experimentally or predict that they have a [non-zero electric dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_electric_dipole_moment)?

Comment: Why would neutrons having and EDM be contradictory?  Neutrons are not fundemantal particles being a composite of quarks.

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome I can't see a way how hypothetically zero EDM quarks combining would generate a non-zero EDM Neutron unless the quarks would also have a non-zero EDM.

Comment: I'm not aware of an experiment that can isolate and measure the possible electric dipole moment of a quark even in quark-gluon plasma configuration. However, it seems that there are some predictions about non-zero electric dipole moment of quarks contributing to the measured electric dipole moment of a neutron: https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08438

Comment: See [The Neutron EDM in the SM : A Review](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0008248), there may be newer results.  My take is that the SM allows for a non-zero EDM but doesn't require it.

Comment: Quarks cannot be studied in isolation, and so the issue of measuring/determining a nonzero EDM for them is extraordinarily pie-in-the-sky "academic".

Comment: @CosmasZachos I agree experimentally. However, why the gluons bonding them thus the strong force, would act as a fluxgate similar to a solenoid's inner flux unless the quarks charge flux would resemble a helix? Therefore a non-zero electric dipole moment? There are strong clues that quarks have a possible non-zero EDM.

Comment: No clues, let alone strong ones, that I know of. Are you making all this up?